# Center axis labels above axis arrows in coordinate plot

Tags: pgfplots, labels, axis

I need a coordinate system with four quadrants and what to center the labels over the x- and y-axis arrows.

I am able to do this manually using `xshift` and `yshift` but I would prefer to have something which automatically centers the labels.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\let\Re\undefined
\let\Im\undefined
\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}

%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        font=\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont,
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=center,
            no markers,
            cycle list name=exotic,
            xlabel={$\Re\left(\alpha\right)$},
            ylabel={$\Im\left(\alpha\right)$},
            xmin=-1,
            xmax=+1,
            ymin=-1,
            ymax=+1,
            x label style={
                at={(ticklabel cs:1.0)},
                anchor=north,
                rotate=90,
                xshift=16,
            },
            y label style={
                at={(ticklabel cs:1.1)},
                xshift=12.0
            },
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: preview tex]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `axis description cs:` where bottom left is at `(0,0)` and top right is at `(1,1)`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\let\Re\undefined
\let\Im\undefined
\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        font=\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont,
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=center,
            no markers,
            cycle list name=exotic,
            xlabel={$\Re\left(\alpha\right)$},
            ylabel={$\Im\left(\alpha\right)$},
            xmin=-1,
            xmax=+1,
            ymin=-1,
            ymax=+1,
            x label style={
                at={(axis description cs:1,0.5)},
                anchor=north,
                rotate=90,
            },
            y label style={
                at={(axis description cs:0.5,1)},
                anchor=south,
                  },
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Coordinate system]

Comment: At ˙`pgfplots` version 1.17 you can define axis labels style as `x label style={at={(1,0.5)}, anchor=north,rotate=90},
y label style={at={(0.5,1)}, anchor=south},`.

Answer (score 1):

It is also to obtain what you want with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\psset{unit=3cm, arrowinset=0.12, linejoin=1, showorigin=false}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.1,-1.1)(1.1,1.1)
\psaxes[linewidth=1pt, Dx=0.5, Dy=0.5]{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(1.1,1.1)%ce
\uput[u](0,1.1){$ \im(\alpha) $}
\uput[r]{90}(1.1,0){$ \re(\alpha) $}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]